# Why i am not seeing a .py file but something else (trying to create Django project)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

So I got advice in another question and they started talking about paths and .exe and that I should not put my projects in the scripts. So I added 
C:python27\scripts to my path and nothing seemed to change except when I created a new project, and went into the GUI to look for the folder and found it, it just says Manage instead of manage.py. It says its a python folder.

I then took ..\scripts out of the path and created the project again and still got the same thing.

Whenever I did it the first time without changing anything, I did see a manage.py file.

So the tutorial I am working that introduces me to Django asked me to open the manage.py file, and when I try to of course it tells me it can't open the file because it does exist. So what do I do?

Comment: "GUI to look for the folder and found it, it just says Manage instead of manage.py" Doesn't windows strip extensions?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're simply trying to create a django project. Since you didn't mention which tutorial you're using, I'll link [this resource](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) and recommend following it page for page. It's a great walk-through for learning how to create apps and it's broken into sessions you can do over a period of time:

To answer your question: when you create a django project with `django-admin startproject mysite` it will install the manage.py into the `mysite` directory. If that doesn't answer your question, try describing the precise steps you're taking to create a Django project including all commands you're using (if any).

It's also helpful to know if you're using a virtual environment.